# Any good way to debug Self Hosted https connection issues?

Tags: https, servicestack

I am working with a self-hosted servicestack webservice on a Windows 10 machine and I am trying to enable https on it.  What I have done so far is this:

1) I have created a wildcard cert using our companies cert server and exported it with the private key.

2) I have installed the cert on my dev machines' "LocalMachine/Personal" cert store.

3) I have run the following commands from the command line:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{DefaultConfig.DefaultSslPort} certhash={sha1} appid={{{appId}}}
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:{DefaultConfig.DefaultSslPort}/ user=everyone
```

4) I added the following to my Program.cs

```
var listeningOn = $"http://*:{DefaultConfig.DefaultPort}/";
appHost.Start(new[]{ listeningOn, $"https://*:{DefaultConfig.DefaultSslPort}/" });
```

Now when I launch the project, the http binding works no problem the webservice loads and works as expected.  However when I try the https binding, the browser shows that a connection was made and the cert is valid (green lock appears and network traffic shows connection succeeding) however the server responds with:

```
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

Clearly it is available (as the Http binding proves) but there is some disconnect between windows and servicestack and I don't really know where to look for answers on this.  I have tried a bunch of search phrases but they all seem to tell me to check/do what I have already checked/done or the results are specific to a particular application/framework/OS and have not been helpful.

Comment: I am accessing the https endpoint by typing in h t t p s : / / myDevMachineName.MyCompany.com:DefaultSslPort/  since the wildcard cert is for *.MyCompany.com the lock appears green which as far as I know means the browser is happy.

Comment: I have started a blank self-hosted servicestack project from the servicestack templates.  Performed steps 1-4.  Same result.  Works in http, fails https.

Comment: Tried adding a firewall rule to allow any connection on my sslPort (just in case firewall was blocking something).  No luck (makes sense since if my firewall was blocking that port my browser should not have show a green 'lock' indicating a successful ssl connection).

Comment: I can telnet into the host:port, so connection is definitely open and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so counter to MANY MANY MANY posts out there, you should *NOT* reserve the url using:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:{DefaultConfig.DefaultSslPort}/ user=everyone
```

When self-hosting with ServiceStack.  I don't know why (if you know why, feel free to post a comment) but this makes windows unable to pass the https request down to your self-hosted site.  I checked this by downloading ServiceStack source code and put a break point on the connection callback that is the entry point for any incoming connections.  The breakpoint is never hit, therefore the request never gets to Servicestack.

Once I removed the URL reservation, everything worked fine.

Comment: Looks like this is a result of running the site from the command-line during development.  If you are running the website as a console app, reserving the URL causes problems (again I'm not sure why).  However, in production, when the site is running as a stand-alone windows service, the URL acl must be reserved otherwise you get an "access denied" error when you try to start the webservice.